# How to create regex expression for 3 links at once

Tags: java, regex

I created regex expression in JAVA for 2 links at once:

1. https://downloads.test.test.testagain.tes/test-test/test/te25st24w/te43s5t25x/0twt42ts/test0218.pdf
2. https://downloads.test.test.testagain.tes/test-test/test/te25st24w/te43s5t25x/0twt42ts/TestTes-09-05-2018.pdf

Regex:
String REGEX_LINK = "https:..downloads.test.test.testagain.tes.test-test.test."

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( REGEX_LINK + ".[\w*/]*.((\d{2}-\d{2}-)?\d{4}).pdf" );

But I have to create regex expression for 3 links at once and I don't know how to do that, I need help with this:

1. https://downloads.test.test.testagain.tes/test-test/test/te25st24w/te43s5t25x/0twt42ts/test0218.pdf
2. https://downloads.test.test.testagain.tes/test-test/test/te25st24w/te43s5t25x/0twt42ts/TestTes-09-05-2018.pdf
3. https://downloads.test.test.testagain.tes/test-test/test/te25st24w/te43s5t25x/0twt42ts/01-01-18_Testt_Testing_ASB_Test_Final.pdf

I have to create one regex expression to extract String from 1 link: "0218", from 2 link: "09-05-2018", from 3 link: "01-01-18"

Maybe someone has a any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match 2 times 2 digits with an optional hyphen, and then optionally 4 or 2 digits preceded by a hyphen.

Note that the pattern by itself does not verify a valid date.

```
(?<!\d)(\d{2}-?\d{2}(?:-(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))?)\S*\.pdf\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\d)` Negative lookbehind, assert not a digit to the left
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d{2}-?\d{2}` Match 2 digits, optional hyphen and 2 digits
  - `(?:-(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))?` Optionally match `-` and either 4 or 2 digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `\S*` Match optional non whitespace chars
- `\.pdf\b` Match a dot and `pdf` followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bmSAuB/1)

Or if there can not be any other digits following till the end of the string:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{2}-?\d{2}(?:-(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))?)[^\d\s]*\.pdf\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4E9eIW/1)

Comment: @Vi like this https://regex101.com/r/hTfFDd/1 or a bit more specific https://regex101.com/r/y0MiUK/1